# Computing the sum $S_k=1\times 2 + 2\times3+\cdots+(k-1) \times k$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $S_k=1\times 2 + 2\times3+\cdots+(k-1) \times k$.  How can I get a closed form for $S_k$?

Comment: Do you know how to evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^k n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^k n^2$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
S_k
& =\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}i\cdot(i+1)
=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}i^2+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}i \\
& =\frac{(k-1)\cdot k\cdot(2k-1)}6+\frac{(k-1)\cdot k}2\\
&=\frac{k^3-k}3
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

notice that
$$
i(i+1) = \frac{1}{3}\left[(i+1)^3 - i^3 - 1\right]
$$

thus
$$
S_k = \sum_{i=1}^{i-1} i(i+1) = \frac{1}{3} \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} [(i+1)^3 - i^3 -1] = \frac{k^3 - 1^3 -(k-1)}{3} = \frac{k^3-k}{3}
$$